# creating side-by-side violin plots in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to create side-by-side violin plots using Matplotlib and Seaborn, but I'm having trouble getting them to display properly (I kept finding that they would be superimposed). I want to compare the average Phast scores for different element types in my dataset. Currently, my code displays the violin plots as separate subplots.

```
# Create a new figure and subplots with 1 row and 2 columns
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

# First violin plot
sns.violinplot(
    y=df['avg_phast_score'],
    x=df['main_category'],
    ax=axes[0]  # Assign the first subplot to the first column
)
# Set title and labels for the first subplot
axes[0].set_title('element regions')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Element Type')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Average Phast Score')
axes[0].set_ylim([-.1, .2])  # Set the y-axis limits for the first subplot
axes[0].set_xticklabels(axes[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)  # Rotate x-axis labels

# Second violin plot
sns.violinplot(
    y=df['control_score'],
    x=df['main_category'],
    ax=axes[1]  # Assign the second subplot to the second column
)

# Set title and labels for the second subplot
axes[1].set_title('control')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Element Type')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Average Phast Score')
axes[1].set_ylim([-.1, .2])  # Set the y-axis limits for the second subplot
axes[1].set_xticklabels(axes[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)  # Rotate x-axis labels

# Adjust the spacing between the subplots
plt.tight_layout()
# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `hue=final_df["element_type"]`, while plotting the violinplot? This would allow you to see average score for each element type. Ref [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)

Answer (score 0):

you're utilizing two separate DataFrame objects in your code snippet: **final_df** and **df**. Ensure that the appropriate DataFrame is being used for each subplot.

you must give the labels as a list of strings when using set_xticklabels to set the x-axis labels. You may use the rotation parameter in the same way that you did to rotate the labels.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

sns.violinplot(
    y=final_df['avg_phast_score'],
    x=final_df['main_category'],
    ax=axes[0]
)


axes[0].set_title('Element Regions')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Element Type')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Average Phast Score')
axes[0].set_ylim([-0.1, 0.2])  # Set the y-axis limits for the first subplot
axes[0].set_xticklabels(axes[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)  

sns.violinplot(
    y=df['control_score'],
    x=df['main_category'],
    ax=axes[1] 
)

axes[1].set_title('Control')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Element Type')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Average Phast Score')
axes[1].set_ylim([-0.1, 0.2])  
axes[1].set_xticklabels(axes[1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)  

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: just edited it to be correct

Comment: This code still keeps the plots as subplots, but side-by-side on one plot.